# Detect if line contains some digit and alphabetic string pattern

Tags: java

I have line like this:

```
|date=[[19 Februari]] [[1942]] – [[10 Februari]] [[1943]]
```

I want to check if my line contains a string like this:

```
[[19 Februari]] [[1942]]
```

Which is, I think, suitable pattern for that is:

```
"(?s)(\\[)(\\[)[0-9]+(\\s)[abc]+(\\])(\\])(?s)"
```

I have tried:

```
public static void dumpDateTagger(String string) {

    if(string.contains("–") || string.contains("-")){

        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(?s)(\\[)(\\[)[0-9]+(\\s)[abc]+(\\])(\\])(?s)");
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(string);

        if(matcher1.find()){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }

}
```

Why this doesn't work and never find pattern im looking for?

Comment: Try `"(?i)\\[\\[\\d+\\s+[a-z]+\\]\\]\\s+\\[\\[\\d+\\]\\]"`.

Comment: What are all the groups for?

Comment: It works! @saka1029

Comment: looking for string with specific pattern using regex @shmosel

Comment: Yeah I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(
            "\\[\\[\\d{1,2}\\s\\w+\\]\\]\\s\\[\\[\\d{4}\\]\\]");
    String line = "|date=[[19 Februari]] [[1942]] – [[10 Februari]] [[1943]]";
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(line);
    System.out.println(matcher1.find());
```

Prints

> true

`[abc]` matches lowercase letters a, b and c. One way to match any English letter is `\\w`. Edit: The `(?s)` that you used is a so-called *flag expression*  and controls whether the dot character can match a newline. Since there are no dots in the regular expression, we can safely leave `(?s)` out.

If additionally you want to validate that a valid date has been found, put the day of month, month and year together to a new string and try parsing it into a `LocalDate`.

Edit: I have changed the code to accept 3 and 4 digit years (if you need to accept 1 or 2 digit years, just change the regular expression accordingly).

```
    // Round brackets delimit capturing groups.
    // \d{3,4} matches 3 or 4 digits for year.
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(
            "\\[\\[(\\d{1,2})\\s(\\w+)\\]\\]\\s\\[\\[(\\d{3,4})\\]\\]");
    Locale malay = Locale.forLanguageTag("ms");
    // d and u match day-of-month and year in any number of digits.
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM u", malay);
    // Test with 3 digit year.
    String line = "|date=[[2 Januari]] [[934]] – [[4 Oktober]] [[958]]";
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(line);
    if (matcher1.find()) {
        String date = matcher1.group(1) + ' ' + matcher1.group(2) + ' ' + matcher1.group(3);
        try {
            LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);
            System.out.println("yes: " + localDate1);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("no: " + dtpe.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
```

I got

> yes: 0934-01-02

In the pattern I have added round brackets to define the groups that `group(int)` takes out into the new string. Please substitute your desired locale. I used Malay (`ms`), but “Februari” could be Indonesian (`id` or `in`), maybe other languages too.

Comment: This one works! Thankyou. But, what is Pattern.DOTALL for? @Ole V.V.

Comment: Leave out `DOTALL`. It was an attempt to obtain what you obtained with `(?s)`, but it makes no difference in this case, as I am explaining in my edit.

Comment: why the second code won't work on me? i got error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1 @Ole V.V.

Comment: Did you notice that the pattern is slightly different in the second snippet? I have added round brackets to define the groups that `group(int)` tries to take out. So it doesn’t work without them,

Comment: what if for the last digit i want it catch 3 to 4 digit? since there is year with 3 digit number. i try \\[\\[(\\d{1,2})\\s(\\w+)\\]\\]\\s\\[\\[(\\d{3,4})\\]\\] but it doesn't work @Ole V. V.

Comment: @Acantya See my edit. `{3,4}` is correct for accepting at least 3 and not more than 4 digits. We also needed to change the date format pattern string since `uuuu` requires (at least) 4 digits. `u` alone just requires at least 1 digit so works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

- If the brackets are not significant I'd recommend removing them before attempting regex, this avoiding having a very complex regex.
- Just write the regex for the date once and call .find() twice, again simpler regex
- As Adya has suggested I'd also using built-in Java date-time parsing functions.

Example

```
String line = "|date=[[19 Februari]] [[1942]] – [[10 Februari]] [[1943]]";
String withoutBrackets = line.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+ \\w+ \\d{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(withoutBrackets);

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM uuuu", Locale.forLanguageTag("ms"));

if (matcher.find()) {
    String dateStr1 = matcher.group(1);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr1, dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
}
if (matcher.find()) {
    String dateStr2 = matcher.group(1);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr2, dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```